# django: many to many relations on raw queries

Tags: django, django-models

when I get an object returned from a rawqueryset like:

```
peo = Entity.objects.raw('SELECT * ...')
return peo[0]
```

I have the list of all object attributes and its many-to-many related ones for the first tuple in queryset but if I pick a list of that objects, like the following

```
return peo[0:3]
```

my list does not include many-to-many related attributes.

How can I obtain a list of that objects where many-to-many relations are followed (as single object example) ?

By adding single objects to an array did not make the trick neither a select_related().

thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you use raw sql, you will need to use sql JOINs to get related objects.

Comment: Ok but how can I obtain the full entity for related objets ? IE: if I add a column as the related_oject.name in select, I get only that...I need the list of entire related entities with their attributes (to be returned as JSON).

thank you

Comment: @WonderBoy: You should try to avoid using raw sql in django unless you have a very *very* **very** (very) good reason.

Comment: @Udi : I see usage of `raw` query quite often to leverage window functions & CTEs. Not sure why all the emphasis on not using raw as long as you parameterize the queries.